# How to Test a Spring Boot 1.2.7 Application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I need to test old Spring Boot Java application (version of **Spring Boot 1.2.7**, **Java 1.8**) and I don't want to change Spring version (because the application is very voluminous and then I will have to refactor the code very much).

I'd like to apply to input of my desktop application different table column types and test that application determines them correctly.

But the problem is that due to old version of Spring I can't pull up annotations like @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class), @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class), or @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) to enable spring boot features, or @SpringBootTest to load complete application context for end-to-end integration testing.

**I'm using the following dependencies for tests**:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I tried to upgrade the version of Spring dependencies for testing (to be able to include annotations) and keep the Spring version of existing project but then initialization errors occured.

How can I enable spring boot features for testing?

Comment: Time to upgrade. [Log4shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4Shell) (if no other reason).

Comment: You kinda have to upgrade... There are unpatched security vulnerabilities that can cost you more than refactoring...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most recommended solution would be to upgrade the entire project. If not, the easiest solution is to rely on `spring-boot-starter-test`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This means you'll have to rely on JUnit 4 and older versions of Mockito, AssertJ and the Spring testing library.

These are the annotations you can use:

- `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` / `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` → `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`
- `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` → `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`
- `@SpringBootTest` → `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` (not an exact replacement)

Test slices (`@DataJpaTest`, `@WebMvcTest`) were introduced in **Spring boot 1.4**, so you can't rely on those either.

The best way to find out what is possible, is by checking the  [reference documentation of Spring boot 1.2.7](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing).
One example they show is:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SampleDataJpaApplication.class)
public class CityRepositoryIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    CityRepository repository;

    // ...

}
```

Comment: I have already read that reference documentation. The problem is that I can't use @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class). If I understood correctly now class [SpringJUnit4ClassRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html) available since 2.5 (there is also "NOTE: As of Spring Framework 4.3, this class requires JUnit 4.12 or higher").

But @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) and @SpringApplicationConfiguration are working

Comment: @Aricann The 2.5 is Spring framework 2.5. Spring boot 1.2.7 relies on Spring framework 4.1.8 ([source](https://spring.io/blog/2015/10/16/spring-boot-1-2-7-available-now)) so that shouldn't be a problem. That also means that the JUnit 4.12 rule doesn't apply. Even if it did apply, the benefit of those Spring boot starters is that they guarantee that those internal versions all match. Maybe you're loading some other versions of Spring somewhere that are causing this conflict.

Comment: Thanks for the details, managed to enable the annotation @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class). Problem was in dependencies

Comment: Is there some way to pass command line arguments like @SpringBootTest({"arg1=val1"}) via @SpringApplicationConfiguration?